# How to make `.draggable` preview the same as the view being dragged in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I have a bit of confusion on the `.draggable` modifier in SwiftUI. I'm playing around with the overload that lets us pass in a view for the drag preview, but I cannot figure out how the framing/layout works for this preview. Below is the code I'm messing with:

```swift
@State private var items: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .green, .orange, .purple]

var body: some View {
  VStack(spacing: 16) {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { color in
      color
        .frame(height: 100)
        .draggable(color) {
          color
            .frame(height: 100)
        }
    }
  }
  .padding()
}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the preview barely takes any width, and the height is clearly much greater than the `100` height of the color in the VStack. Why is this? Is there something about the preview's context that changes the framing behavior?

Furthermore, is there a way to set the frame exactly to that of the original view? Or even more ideally, is there a way to set the preview to *exactly* the view of the original (in this case just the color with the same frame), so that it looks like we're dragging the original view?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the `preview` of the `draggable` modifier is interfering with size of the View. My personal solution would be to simulate the dragging behavior by using a combination of `gestures` and `overlay` while still keeping the `draggable` modifier.

Here's an example based on your code. First I've declared a `struct` conforming to `Identifiable` (to distinguish the selected one from the others) holding a color:

```
struct DraggableColor: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let color: Color
}
```

And the View is as follows:

```
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var draggedColor: DraggableColor?
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    var draggableColors: [DraggableColor] = [.init(color: .blue), .init(color: .red), .init(color: .green), .init(color: .yellow)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(draggableColors) { color in
                color.color
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .draggable(color.color) {}
                    .overlay {
                        color.color
                            .frame(height: 100)
                            /// To only make the selected color move
                            .offset(x: draggedColor?.id == color.id ? offset.width : 0,
                                    y: draggedColor?.id == color.id ? offset.height : 0)
                            .gesture(
                                /// Long Press gesture to simulate the draggable press minimum duration
                                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.3).onEnded({ value in
                                    draggedColor = color
                                })
                                .simultaneously(with: DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                    .onChanged({ value in
                                        guard draggedColor != nil else { return }
                                        offset = value.translation
                                    })
                                    .onEnded({ value in
                                        withAnimation(.smooth) {
                                            offset = .zero
                                        }
                                    }))
                            )
                    }
                    /// Since the the colors appearing first go behind the colors appearing next
                    .opacity((offset != .zero && draggedColor?.id != color.id) ? 0.1 : 1)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
    }
```

I've used a `LongPressGesture` to simulate the prolongued tap to trigger the `draggable` modifier. I've set it to 0.3s, you can change it to fit your needs, of course.

This is simply a workaround, of course. If you find a solution for the native modifier it would be better and less complicated then this.
Among the issues I've found is that when dragging colors they will go behind the ones appearing below, that's why I've used the `opacity`. I also tried used the `zIndex` but with no luck.

Here's the result:

[image: Draggable Colors]

Let me know if your liks this solution!

Comment: Doesn't the gesture conflict with the `draggable` modifier? If you just add the `.gesture` with the `LongPressGesture` and add a simple view in the preview closure of `.draggable`, you'll notice that the drag preview never shows up.

If this is the case we can't take advantage of the features that come with `.draggable` like `.dropDestination`

Comment: If you turn the opacity to zero to the overlayed rectangle you'll see the preview show up. So, it doesn't seem it is conflicting to me. Try it. The preview is being hidden by the overlay

Comment: Yeah, this maybe could work as a workaround.... but it certainly feels like we're fighting against the modifier. Seems Apple could greatly improve this.

Comment: And yes Apple should definitely impress this but so far this is the only solution I could think of. But, it does work, I correct? Did you try it?

Comment: Have you gotten it to work with reordering (drag/drop to reorder)?

Comment: No, because in your original code there was no drop destination. I could try it though. Anyway, I would appreciate if you could at least upvote the answer if it helped you in anyway.

Comment: Was just curious if you had tried, wondering if it could work... anyway I upvoted! If it works with drag/drop then I suppose for all intents and purposes it is the correct answer to my question, and I will mark it as such.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. Well, that's the theory in fact. It should be working with everything the draggable modifier is supposed to.

Comment: Actually - in your code, do you ever set `draggedColor` to `nil`? If not then after a long+press drag (+ animation end), dragging anywhere will move the previously dragged color, even if you aren't touching it.

Comment: Also, I do not believe drag/drop works with this code due to the overlay.

Comment: But as I said, if you turn the opacity to zero you see the draggable preview. And draggedColor is updated at every new touch in the LongPressGesture, you can see it's not the case by the gif above too where I move two colours. I don't get why you still haven't tried it yet. Just try it and let me know if this works, if not we'll see what we can do.

Comment: I have tried it with no luck. I can post this particular case as a new question if that would make more sense.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. That's ok, post it as a follow up question then and I'll have a look.

Comment: I have posted an updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183766/how-to-add-drag-drop-support-to-a-view-while-making-the-drag-preview-the-same-as